# ssl cert validation bypass does not fire on windows server 2016

Tags: .net, ssl, ssl-certificate

Any idea why this below is not executed when running on Windows Server 2016?

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
        (se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("cert checked!");
            return true;
        };
```

It runs perfect on Windows 2012.

any quick idea much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons is that actually it runs only when server responds :)
In my case server was not responding so obviously no validation will occur.